# ST-Link V2 forgets its firmware upgrade

Tags: stm32, st-link

My ST-Link V2 is the low cost memory stick kind from China. It works, but every time I re-power it, it needs to upgrade the firmware and that works too.  Is this normal; should it not remember the firmware from a precious upgrade?

Comment: So it works, but it doesn't? It's not normal for an genuine ST-Link but it might be normal for your non-genuine clone claiming to be an ST-Link. You could try asking the clone manufacturer for support, but you will get none, that's why they are so cheap. Buy a real ST-Link from ST, it will be worth it.

Comment: Instead of buying full ST-Link you can buy NUCLEO-C031C6 which cost about only 10 USD and contains on-board ST-link capable of programming external STM32s. 10 USD is not very far from ST-link clone price if you take in account that except ST-link you get full-featured development kit with genuine chip of course.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is unsupported, so *any* behaviour can be expected.

ST don't support (and have been trying to prevent) using their official ST-Link firmware upgrades being applied to the clone ST-Link products.

We've seen people here reporting that ST's firmware upgrades don't recognise some clones too. Again. not a surprise.

Sorry for the news. If you want/need to have the upgraded firmware (e.g. to support new STM32 devices) then get a genuine ST-Link from a reputable supplier (some disreputable suppliers claim they are selling genuine devices, even in genuine-looking plastic cases, but they aren't - one of my friends got caught out with this).

Comment: I got information on the Chinese clone devices from the ST website ... they don't seem to care and for sure ( at least in my mind) having inexpensive ST-Link devices drives sales and use of ST chips.

Comment: Could you please provide link to ST website where did you find information on Chinese clones?